# Circle rows in a matrix and add comments aside

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, drawing

I am trying to modify my `bmatrix` by circling a row, and adding a `\sum` symbol as well as circling few other components and writing above them, as seen in figure below:

[image]

My matrix code is the following:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{equation}
        \textcolor{blue}{\sum}
        Y_{\mathrm{RLC}}=
        \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=brace,baseline]
            \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},ampersand replacement=\&] {
                \dfrac{1}{jL_1\omega}+\dfrac{1}{jL_2\omega}+jC_1\omega \& -\dfrac{1}{jL_2\omega} \& -\dfrac{1}{R_3} \\
                -\dfrac{1}{jL_2\omega} \& \dfrac{1}{jL2\omega}+\dfrac{1}{R_1}+jC_2\omega \& -jC_2\omega \\
                -\dfrac{1}{R_3} \& -jC_2\omega \& jC_2\omega+\dfrac{1}{R_2} \\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you used `matrix` in a `tikzpicture`, you just have to use the names of the matrix cells to draw around them, i.e. `(m-1-1)`, `(m-2-1)`, ... , `(m-3-3)`, in this case.

[image: drawing in a tikz matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
       Y_{\mathrm{RLC}}=
        \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=brace,baseline]
            \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},ampersand replacement=\&] {
                \dfrac{1}{jL_1\omega}+\dfrac{1}{jL_2\omega}+jC_1\omega \& -\dfrac{1}{jL_2\omega} \& -\dfrac{1}{R_3} \\
                -\dfrac{1}{jL_2\omega} \& \dfrac{1}{jL2\omega}+\dfrac{1}{R_1}+jC_2\omega \& -jC_2\omega \\
                -\dfrac{1}{R_3} \& -jC_2\omega \& jC_2\omega+\dfrac{1}{R_2} \\
            };
            
        % Sum of line 1
        \node[blue,thick,inner ysep=1pt, inner xsep=10pt,fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-3),draw,rounded corners=15pt](ell){};
        \node[blue,left= 1mm of ell]{$\sum$};
        \node[blue,right= 1mm of ell]{$=Y'_{11}$};

        % left circle
        \draw[blue,thick] (m-3-1) circle [radius=5.5mm] node[below=15pt] {$-Y'_{12}$};

        % right circle
        \draw[blue,thick] (m-3-2) circle [radius=5.5mm] node[below=15pt] {$-Y'_{13}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! However is there a way to customize the placement of '= Y11'? The fact that it is placed spot on the bracket is a little unfortunate :(

Comment: I ended up adding ```\qquad``` to the equations ;)

Comment: You can also manage to push it by modifying `\node[blue,right= 1mm of ell]{$=Y'_{11}$};` to another distance.

Comment: is there a way to add this command \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} to my matrix?